# how to post to webapi in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

when i run my app and post data in chrome it shows the following error: POST http://10.10.9.169/UserService/api/account 401 (Unauthorized)

i already installed cors and enabled it in the webapiconfig.cs file, and i also added the following in the global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

here is my controllers.js code:

```
.controller('SignUp15Ctrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location','userFactoryReg', function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, userFactoryReg) {
    $scope.userdataReg = {}
    $scope.enterloginReg = function(usern,pass1,pass2) {
        if(pass1!=pass2)
        {
            alert('Passwords do not match.');
        }
        if(pass1 == pass2)
        {
            userFactoryReg.postUser(usern,pass1,pass2).then(function(response)
            {
                if(JSON.stringify(response.data) === "null")
                {
                    alert('Error');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Accoiunt successfully created.');
                    $location.path('/page4');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

and here is my services.js code:

```
.factory('userFactoryReg', ['$http', function($http) {
    var users = [];
    return {
        postUser: function(uname,passw1,passw2){
            return $http.post("http://10.10.9.169/UserService/api/account/register", {"Username" :uname, "Password" :passw1, "ConfirmPassword" :passw2} );
        }
    }
}])
```

and here is my code for webapi part:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] User user)
{
    try
    {
        using (UsersDBEntities entities = new UsersDBEntities())
        {
            entities.Users.Add(user);
            entities.SaveChanges();

            var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
            message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + user.Username.ToString());

            return message;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have authentication required globally, have you added `[AllowAnonymous]` on your login action?

Comment: i tried adding [allowanonymous] but it returns : POST http://10.10.9.169/UserService/api/account 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Could you add the code for that API action to your question?

Comment: added. not sure if i did it right.

Comment: Your action seems to return a 400 if you get an exception, could you put a breakpoint there and see what it is?

Comment: ex {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."} System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException}

Comment: Probably something missing from the user object, put a breakpoint at the start of the action and inspect it.

Comment: got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was caused by not having [AllowAnonymous] on the API action and requiring authentication with [Authorize] globally or at controller-level. You have to allow non-authenticated users to hit the authentication endpoint.

Second problem was getting back an HTTP 400, but that was due to a validation error in the `User` entity.